# Google rules for FindBugs

Tags: java, checkstyle, findbugs

I noticed that Google uses/supports FindBugs. Does anybody know about a rules file they use, and can share a link? Similarly to their checkstyle rules, maybe there would be something for FindBugs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's true that Google appreciates FindBugs, as evidenced by the "[Great Google FindBugs Fixit](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~ayewah/web/pubs/Google-ISSTA2010.pdf)" or (maybe) the fact that some FindBugs stuff is still [hosted on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/findbugs/source/browse/) (although [Google Code is shutting down](http://google-opensource.blogspot.de/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html)).

You referred to [Google Java Style](http://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), which recently became a popular coding convention, sometimes replacing the original Sun Conventions. The Checkstyle team [decided to adopt Google Style](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/google_style.html) and include it as a default ruleset. This decision was the Checkstyle team's, though, and did not involve Google the company.

To my knowledge, Google did not officially publish rule sets for any static analysis tools. Maybe you could contact the originators of the before-mentioned "FindBugs Fixit" to get their rule set.

Another way to get a head start might be to look at the SonarQube ruleset "[Sonar Way with FindBugs](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#qprofile=java-sonar-way-with-findbugs-93000|activation=true|languages=java)". The SonarQube team spent some time selecting the rules and eliminating duplicates with other code analyzers.